# Hosting chrome extension in github

Tags: github, google-chrome-extension

I have developed a chrome extension and want to know how to host the .crx in github.

I also saw this that's similar to mine (i.e. hosted in github): 
https://github.com/franverona/MarkAsRead-Chrome-Extension

but the installation instructions seem complicated (haven't tested even that will work).

Q:
Has anyone succeeded in hosting .crx in github and have users install it with just a click?
(basically satisfying header constraints given by google at 
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/hosting.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, so this is what ended up:

1. Hosting in our own server doesn't work in latest versions of chrome. It directed me to google chrome's support section stating that they have disabled it altogether for security reasons
2. So the only option left (as i didn't want to host it in chrome web store) is manual install - users have to download my extension and drag and drop it onto chrome://extensions page
3. I chose google code (downloads section) as compared to github for hosting my .crx because in github download is not straightforward. 
   More details: in github user has to download in 'raw'. It may not be straightforward for users - if they say 'Save as' against .crx without going to raw view then they end up getting git mashed up file (in other words not the original file we upload)